# getchar() won't keep the console open

Tags: c, scanf

I'm writing this code to compare two strings. The code works, my only problem being keeping the console open after it finishes. Normally, getchar() works like a charm, but in this case it is simply ineffective. I think it's due to the if-else functions. How do I keep the console open?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 50

int main (int argc , char** argv) {
    char isim[SIZE];
    printf("Adinizi yazin:\n");
    scanf("%s", isim);
    if(strcmp(isim, "Cihan") == 0)
        printf("Hosgeldiniz!\n");
    else
        printf("Cihan degilsiniz. Lutfen programi terk edin.\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use two `getchar()`, one after the other. `scanf()` doesn't remove the newline character from the input buffer, so first `getchar()` "eats" that newline. The second `getchar()` to wait for next input, which will keep the console open.

From [`scanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) page in cplusplus.com:

> the function will read and **ignore** any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character (whitespace characters include spaces, newline and tab characters -- see isspace).

Emphasis by me.

Answer (score 1):

The input is sent to the program after a newline, but

```
scanf("%s", &isim );
```

leaves the newline in the input buffer, since the `%s` format stops when the first whitespace character is encountered after some non-whitespace. `getchar()` then returns that newline immediately and doesn't wait.

To make your code work, try something like this

```
scanf("%s", &isim );
while( getchar() != '\n' ){ 
  /* flush to end of input line */ 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm really just a beginner and there are some very basic stuff that I don't know. Your explanation is very appreciated.

Comment: Accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use statement: **getch();** in **conio.h** header. **getch()** not read character in buffer, it read character directly from keyboard. So console will open if you not yet input. **getchar()** read character from buffer,a newline in your input buffer after **scanf()** not be read and save in buffer. Then **getchar()** will read **newline** and statement stop, console will close.

Comment: Why? How is it different from `getchar()`?

Comment: Please describe for the OP's benefit what the problem is and how your answer solves it.

Comment: Because 'getch()' won't read '\n' in buffer when input string.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define SIZE 50

int main (int argc , char** argv) {
char isim[SIZE];
printf("Adinizi yazin:\n");
scanf("%s", &isim);
if(strcmp(isim, "Cihan") == 0)
    printf("Hosgeldiniz!\n");
else
    printf("Cihan degilsiniz. Lutfen programi terk edin.\n");
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are getch() and getchar() any different? I see you use conio for getch. What is the difference?